# Toolbar fills the whole screen

Tags: android, toolbar, drawerlayout

I'm new to the drawer layout and the use of fragments.

I used the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) on creating an activity with a `DrawerLayout`.
It gave me a nullpointer on `getActionBar()`, so I added [a toolbar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) to the activity main and used `getSupportActionBar()` instead.

Now it looks like the toolbar fills the entire screen, because the title is in the middle of the screen and the background of the toolbar is on the whole screen too. Here is the xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've tried replacing the layout_height with 56dp and i've tried making a seperate layout file with the toolbar in it and include it into this xml, but that didn't work.

Why is my Toolbar filling the entire screen?

Comment: What is value of this?:   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: That's 56dp. If I remove it and litterly do layout_height="56dp", it's still full screen.

Comment: Move your theme attributes to before the height attribute (perhaps the height is being set in there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `DrawerLayout` expects *2* Views in it. You supply 3.

The first view is the "background". It is the content of your screen. The second view, the drawer, is  supposed to animate in and out.

You supply 3 views. So your toolbar is "the content"—thus fullscreen, and your drawer is your actual content.

To fix your issue, try something like this:

```
<DrawerLayout>

  <!-- The main content view -->
  <LinearLayout>
    <Toolbar/>
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <!-- The navigation drawer -->
  <ListView/>
</DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Also, there is a bug with the preview in android studio. It shows me a toolbar with only the title and my own toolbar below it. I've made my toolbar red to make  it obvious where it is: http://imgur.com/a/qmc4G

Comment: This is not a bug, but the theme used for your layout. You can change the Theme used in the preview to hide the default one

Comment: I found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909364/why-does-android-studio-always-show-actionbar-in-app-design-even-when-disabled

Answer (score 1):

DrawerLayout will accept only two child views. Try to add the Toolbar in frame layout.
Or you can create like beliw.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- The ActionBar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header"
    app:itemTextColor="#000000"
    app:menu="@menu/global">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```